# Explorer window takes 15 sec to open, queries PostBootReminders\Microsoft.NetDriveReconnectFailed repetedly

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

When opening a new explorer window, there is a long lag time before the the new file browser appears.

I put ProcMon on it, and in the slow sections the following registry key access happens over and over:

`RegQueryKey    HKCU    SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\PostBootReminders\Microsoft.NetDriveReconnectFailed SUCCESS Desired Access: Read
RegCloseKey HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\PostBootReminders\Microsoft.NetDriveReconnectFailed SUCCESS`

After reading the contents of `Microsoft.NetDriveReconnectFailed`, there is a **HALF SECOND** delay, 0.5 to 0.6 sec, then the above keys are queried again.  The below plot shows all the procmon events recorded and the time between events.  The time consuming vertical jumps in the plot are where the above registry keys are queried.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
[image: Procmon event timing]

Comment: do you have any mapped network drives that are currently unavailable?

Comment: No mapped drives. Disconnected all mapped drives when the problem appeared as a first step. Made no difference.